# django runserver startup using local settings when production was identified in .env file

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

I created a new project with cookiecutter django.  I set the environment variable DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True (**setting it to False also causes the .env file to be read btw.  I think that python assumes that the environment variable of True is a string not bool**).

In the .env file there is the following line:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
```

When I run

`python manage.py runserver`

I get the following output:

```
Loading : /home/bucket/src/b2b/.env
The .env file has been loaded. See common.py for more information
Loading : /home/bucket/src/b2b/.env
The .env file has been loaded. See common.py for more information
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 14, 2017 - 20:20:55
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'config.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

According to the above, the server config is config.settings.local.  I know that the .env file is being loaded as the `DATABASE_URL` variable is correct and it connects to the database.

It also looks like the code to load variables from the .env file is being run twice.  I put some print statements in common.py and local.py to trace execution with the results below.

```
Loading : /home/bucket/src/b2b/.env
The .env file has been loaded. See common.py for more information
End of common.py <--
End of local.py <--
Loading : /home/bucket/src/b2b/.env
The .env file has been loaded. See common.py for more information
End of common.py <--
End of local.py <--
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 14, 2017 - 20:22:40
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'config.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Any help or explanation for this behavior would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you might have hit a couple of issues in Cookiecutter-Django. [Issue 1039](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1039) should fix the problem where the environment is read when `DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=False`. [This commit](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/commit/3cd57880e0bfa3d48ecd338fabe7f74e71800f01) might fix the issue where the environment was read twice.

Comment: I did remove the redundant env call and it is still getting called twice.  I was the person who submitted Issue 1039 :-)

Comment: The settings files are being loaded twice only when doing runserver.  If I do a migrate, shell or other command, it only runs them once.

Answer (score 1):

The .env file is intended to use with Docker, but its a great idea!

I'm running a Debian server using Apache and the '.env' file does not work, instead, I must proceed with the 'secrets file pattern' which stores those variables on a json file. If I really want to 'runserver' using the '.env' file, without set any environment variables before on my system, I have to set the following to 'True', in the base.py settings:

```
READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=True)
```

I'm not sure but, the above surpass the 'DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE' informed in the '.env' file. So, you must set 'True' direct in the 'base.py' then it'll be possible to load your settings direct through manage.py:

```
$ python manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.local
or
$ python manage.py runserver --settings=config.settings.production
```